# 4 identical shapes that touch each other?

Tags: mathematics, geometry

It is known that one can have 4 shapes in a plane all touching each other, and not 5. You can add requirements to the 4 shape problem:

- Can you do it with 4 equal triangles? (No)
- Can you do it with 4 equal rectangles? (No)
- Can you do it with 4 triangles with equal area? (Yes) (figure 1)
- Can you do it with 4 equal shapes? (Yes) (figure 2).

My question is: what is the simplest single shape which you can do it with?
(Figure 2 was easy to find, but it looks like it can be improved upon ;-).
(Simpler is undefined, but build from less than 11 squares would fit)
(I could not find a source to this problem. Is there?)

[image]

Comment: Does it count as the same shape if you use its mirror image?

Comment: See [5 geometric shapes, all touching each other](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1550054/237) for why five is impossible.

Comment: @Tweakimp: figure 2 has mirror images. Avoiding this would be nice (just my feeling), but I did not state that requirement. It is a bonus.

Comment: Does the shape have to be continuous?

Comment: @corsiKa, yes. The 4-colour theorem that this problem references doesn’t apply otherwise.

Comment: @corsika: yes. Otherwise you can creatie trivial solutions built from pieces of 3 squares in a row in which the middle one is missing. Solutions made from fractals or complex subsets of complex Numbers will also exist, but those do not fit the requirement 'simpeler'.

Comment: See also [this Mathematic SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4381862/362967) or a solution with mirror-symmetric pieces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems pretty simple

> [image]
>  (each piece has 8 squares and one bend)