# Fewest polyominoes adjacent to 3 copies

Tags: mathematics, geometry, polyomino

What is the smallest positive number of [polyominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino) P, such that

- You can place grid aligned copies of P without any overlap; and
- Each polyomino is adjacent to exactly 3 other polyominoes.

Polyominoes must be the same shape, but can be rotated or flipped. Two polyominoes are considered adjacent if they touch at one of their sides (not vertices).

Comment: See also [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/58751/20814).

Comment: perhaps this is duplicate then?

Comment: It has the same answer, though it is a different question. Theoretically that makes it a duplicate, but I wouldn't insist on it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The minimum number of polyominoes needed is

> 4

Proof:

> [image]
>  This nonomino is the smallest I could find that would work.

Comment: Lovely construction.  Four is the definitely the minimum because each polyomino needs three neighbours.

Comment: I wonder if we can find a smaller polyomino?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky There is an octomino [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/58751/20814).

Comment: oh cool! That must be optimal

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of 4 octominoes, which I believe is the smallest, and also the most compact:

> [image]

[Here Bass has another octomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/58760/84683), as pointed by @Jaap Scherphuis. The shape of his octomino is easier, however, it takes up more space than this one, according to the number of inner white squares.

Comment: Very nice! Are there solutions without any inner space? What about smaller polyominoes?

Comment: I dont think it's possible to achieve this with smaller polyominoes or without any white space.

Comment: If these were physical pieces, would they hold together without falling apart?

Comment: Less white space is possible, see my answer

Comment: If you focus on just the whitespace, you're right. But the overall shape will be bigger, as well as each polyomino. I like your thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

I can reduce the number of inner spaces by 3, by adding 3 cells to each piece in @Lezzup's answer:

> [image]